# How to prevent multiple workers from running a task sent ONLY ONCE?

Tags: celery, celery-3

Recently I noticed a weird Celery (3.1.25) behaviour. A task is queued for execution using the `send_task()` *only once*, however after a while I see multiple running the same task! I have spent hours looking at Celery documentation trying to find out how to prevent this behaviour. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the out of the `inspect active`:

```
...
-> celery1@ec2-256-234-55-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com: OK
    * {'hostname': 'celery1@ec2-256-234-55-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'id': '5bf971b7-c2d2-47a1-9e3e-abec6c3c7ab4', 'args': "['myex', 'equities', 20170103]", 'time_start': 1633747.663716712, 'name': 'parsing.2pass', 'acknowledged': False, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': 'celery', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None, 'routing_key': 'celery'}, 'worker_pid': 28649, 'kwargs': '{}'}
    * {'hostname': 'celery1@ec2-256-234-55-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'id': '5bf971b7-c2d2-47a1-9e3e-abec6c3c7ab4', 'args': "['myex', 'equities', 20170103]", 'time_start': 1637348.143546186, 'name': 'parsing.2pass', 'acknowledged': False, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': 'celery', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None, 'routing_key': 'celery'}, 'worker_pid': 1550, 'kwargs': '{}'}
-> celery1@ec2-54-234-55-254.compute-1.amazonaws.com: OK
    * {'hostname': 'celery1@ec2-256-234-55-254.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'id': '5bf971b7-c2d2-47a1-9e3e-abec6c3c7ab4', 'args': "['myex', 'equities', 20170103]", 'time_start': 1626395.204211438, 'name': 'parsing.2pass', 'acknowledged': False, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': 'celery', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None, 'routing_key': 'celery'}, 'worker_pid': 26978, 'kwargs': '{}'}
-> celery1@ec2-54-226-20-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com: OK
    * {'hostname': 'celery1@ec2-256-226-20-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'id': '5bf971b7-c2d2-47a1-9e3e-abec6c3c7ab4', 'args': "['myex', 'equities', 20170103]", 'time_start': 1630146.08942695, 'name': 'parsing.2pass', 'acknowledged': False, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': 'celery', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None, 'routing_key': 'celery'}, 'worker_pid': 19473, 'kwargs': '{}'}
...
```

Notice that the task `5bf971b7-c2d2-47a1-9e3e-abec6c3c7ab4` is running on at least 3 workers, even though it was triggered by a **single** send_task() call. We use Redis as broker with all the defaults (no fancy exchanges, and routes).

Comment: Can your workers see each other?

Comment: Yes, they are all connected to a single Redis broker...

Comment: Does it have an ETA/countdown argument?  See information about the "visibility timeout" here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#caveats

Comment: Also, have you set up any custom routing options?  Using message routing you can set up broadcast queues (so tasks are sent to all workers), and many other patterns, it's also quite easy to do this by accident if you set up routing manually.

Comment: Nope, I use the defaults for exchange/routing. These nodes are all subscribed to the default queue (*celery*). To answer the first question - no it does not have any ETA/countdown. In fact tasks are configured without any extra parameters. I also have asked here about another weird problem couple of days ago that is somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611281/how-to-prevent-celery-from-running-the-same-task-same-id-on-multiple-workers

Comment: @asksol - no ETA/countdown there. I guess it was a bug in Celery 3 that got fixed as I no longer see this behaviour (I use 4.0.1 now).

Answer (score 1):

There could be several possible reasons for this behaviour.

- Maybe you started celery with celerybeat service. And in this case there should be only one celery process. In other cases every process will schedule the same task.
- Maybe you should adjust yours queues. Since redis is using broadcast messages to deliver a tasks. [More info here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html) Even if you're not using ETA/countdown this could be the reason for duplication

Anyway, you can prevent this on your side by using [celery_once](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery_once/). The main idea is to check within the task if it was promoted and executed already. Yes, this looks like a workaround, but it works pretty good.

Comment: Please note that the task is triggered by a single send_task() call, not by the celerybeat...

Comment: Thanks for the celery_once, I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: Even though this does not answer my question I will award it anyway because at least you tried to help. :)

Comment: @DejanLekic Thank you. I wonder if your tasks are still starting multiple times even with celery_once?